# R: How to remove first column in all items (all = df) of a list?

Tags: r, list, split, col

I want to remove all columns of objects in a list (as list contains only dfs). I need this column previously to split my data, but after the spliting this column must be removed in all objects. Here some example data:

```
 df <- data.frame(IDforSplit=c(25,10,7),
                 valueA =sample(1:10,3),
                 valueB =sample(1:10,3))

splited_df <- split(df, df$IDforSplit)
> splited_df
$`7`
  IDforSplit valueA valueB
3          7      6      7

$`10`
  IDforSplit valueA valueB
2         10      2      6

$`25`
  IDforSplit valueA valueB
1         25      4      4
```

And what I want now is to remove the 1st col, as I need this format to match another dataset. The wished result should be (note that the item-names are important):

```
> splited_df
$`7`
  valueA valueB
3      6      7

$`10`
  valueA valueB
2      2      6

$`25`
  valueA valueB
1      4      4
```

Ideas? Maybe data.table? Thanks

Comment: You can split without the first column `splited_df <- split(df[-1], df$IDforSplit)`

Comment: Great, works fine. Thanks